# Android Play Store - Error retrieving information from server. RPC:S-2:AEC-2

Tags: android, google-play

While installing specific app, the error popup is shown with error: *"appname" could not be downloaded due to error. (Error retrieving information from server. **[RPC:S-2:AEC-2])***

I have already tried

1) restarting device

2) clear data from *google play services*

2) remove google account and sync again

The thing is, every other app is being installed and updated smoothly. I believe that there is something wrong with that specific app (and not with google play. Let me know if i am wrong).
Found the similar question on [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/7Zi3xiplqV8) with same *error code* but with no solution.

Comment: I've got the same issue while downloading a new alpha version of my app from Google Play. Nexus 7 2012, android 5.0.2. The application is published and production version works well on other devices. Any news how it can be fixed?

Comment: In my case, it was resolved with in few hours automatically. What i did was, i updated apk file for Alpha version (it displayed to be updated in few hours) and then after 5 minutes i uploaded updated apk again. After then above error was shown to me on google play. It was resolved after few hours. I think this is the reason so one should not upload updates (apk) multiple times at the same time, i guess

Answer (score 9):

One of my customers had the same issue.
I sent him this link https://support.google.com/googleplay/troubleshooter/4592924?hl=en&rd=1 and it solved the problem.
So try to:

- **Restart your phone** (it helped in my case)
- Check your data connection
- Make sure Download Manager is turned on
- Check your device's available storage
- Clear cache & data
- Reinstall Play Store updates
- Check for system updates

Also, if old version has been installed(or app with same package name, etc.) - try to remove it.
Let me know, if it helps.

Comment: A Restart worked for me.  I am a app tester.  I noticed that Play Store wasn't showing the latest app version on my phone, yet it was on my PC.  A restart fixed this, and I was able to see the latest app and download it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with one of my app being published to prod while an alpha version was not published it. 
Restarting the Phone helped.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all data on the google play services and uninstall all updates do app will go back to the factory version.

I was able to download apps after I did this.